# jquery getting listitem id from its child id

Tags: jquery

```
<li id="l"><a href="#"><img id="i" /></a></li>
```

I have image id and i want listitem id , i know one way

```
$("#i").parent().parent().attr("id");
```

Is there any better way than this?

Comment: A better way would be to not have to guess at the parent id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit simpler:

```
$("#i").parents("li").attr("id")
```

Comment: `parents` will keep bubbling up to select all parents that match the selector. It's best to use `closest` to select only the first parent who matches your selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try `closest` or `find` .

```
$("#i").closest('li').attr("id")
```

Comment: Your code is broken in two places. `$("#i").closest("li").attr("id")`

Comment: fixed they spelling of `closest`. I think he already corrected the other typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#i").closest('li')[0].id;
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

> Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

Comment: Better to use $("#i").closest('li').attr('id').  As written the code assumes the result will contain at least one item-- will crash if it doesn't find any "li".